# State management for Flutter app backed by SQLite

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I am new to Flutter, and I am writing a first app backed by SQLite, using sqflite.

I am familiar with the Flutter architecture, having worked with React, so I understand various patterns of keeping state - from passing down closures from stateful widgets to keeping a single immutable tree with all state and passing various branches downstream. All these techniques work well when your state is fully in memory.

But now I am persisting state into SQLite, which is the definitive source of state in my app. It is easy to do this until everything is read only: pass a handle to the DB to every widget, and every widget can query its own state.

I am trying to figure out a good pattern to handle changes. A possible approach is manual: for every change, do the relevant update in SQLite **and** at the same time call `setState` on every affected widget. But this is error prone. I would like to find a way to mark a widget as dirty, so that it is rerendered from scratch, loading its values from SQLite again. Or possibly there is yet another way I didn't think of.

What are good patterns to keepthe widget state aligned to SQLite?

Comment: What kind of state management do you use? Your widgets should nto know anything about your data store at all. There should be a layer that holds your state and that layer should decide to sometimes save or load it from the database. For example if you are using BLoC, your bloc would have a repository. The states it emits and the widgets that display them know nothing about the database.

Comment: Well, this only moves the problem one layer down, right? Now I have a tree representing my state, I can build a tree of widgets based on that, but I still have the issue of keeping that in sync with the actual database. Right now I am querying the database directly from the widgets because, why not? I appreaciate that there may be architectural patterns that separate data from widgets in a cleaner way, but it only makes sense to adopt them if they simplify state management. I am not sure what BLoC is, but I will have a look